# Bulma CSS: Carousel Image

Tags: css, carousel, bulma

I am new to Bulma css, I am trying to use the carousel features to display pictures collection, I noticed unless the image source is from web source e.g
`<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1200x500" alt="" />`
it won’t display any image but once I tried to use image from my project directory the image won’t display e.g
`<img src= "/Users/mac/Desktop/Newproject/Thirdslide.jpeg" />`

These are my cdn:

````
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/hero.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bulma-modal-fx/dist/css/modal-fx.min.css" />
 <link href="~bulma-carousel/dist/css/bulma-carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="~bulma-carousel/dist/js/bulma-carousel.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-carousel@4.0.4/dist/css/bulma-carousel.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-social@2/css/all.min.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-social@2/css/single/apple/apple.min.css" />```



code of bulma image html I am trying to use :

     <div class='box'>
     <div>
     <figure class="image is-5by3">
     <img src= "/Users/mac/Desktop/Asi4her/Thirdslide.jpeg" />
     </figure>
     </div>
     </div>  



The error I'm getting from terminal is :`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Users/mac/Desktop/NewProject/Thirdslide.jpeg")`
````

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) and [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!, I'm actually using ruby on rails framework so that’s why it keeps throwing errors, so when I tried using ruby html tag :  `<%= image_tag("Firstslide.jpg", :alt => "rss feed") %>`  it worked.